# Alinhar consultas e passar seus resultados como alias para SOMA

Tags: sql

Então, estou executando duas consultas que me retornam a quantidade **X** de itens por mês ao longo de um ano.

A primeira consulta me dá o seguinte resultado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O '`no column name`' seria os meses, então não tenho dados em agosto, novembro e dezembro.

A segunda consulta, me dá o seguinte

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

apenas Agosto e Setembbro tem dados.

O que eu estou tentando descobrir é como somar as duas tabelas para obter o valor de 100%, então defino cada% (corretivas x preventivas). Em minha pesquisa, eu suponho que tenho que aninhar as consultas, mas eu simplesmente não consigo alcançar a lógica para me aproximar do resultado desejado.

esta é a minha pergunta até agora

```
    select month(workOrderDate), COUNT(*) as preventivas from WorkOrder WHERE
    workOrderDescription = 'preventiva'
    AND YEAR(workOrderDate) = 2018
    AND lastUpdateData IS NOT NULL
    AND WorkType = '02'
    group BY MONTH(workOrderDate)
    ORDER BY MONTH(workOrderDate)

    select MONTH(workOrderDate), COUNT(*) AS corretivas from WorkOrder WHERE
    YEAR(workOrderDate) = 2018
    AND workOrderDescription = 'CORRETIVA' 
    AND lastUpdateData IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY MONTH(workOrderDate)
    ORDER BY MONTH(workOrderDate)
```

O resultado esperado seria

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém poderia me ajudar com isso ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20320631/how-to-pivot-a-table-in-mysql-using-case-statements veja se ajuda...

Comment: @Motta Não tem haver com a minha dúvida, mas obrigado por tentar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar um `CASE` (como sugerido pelo [Motta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/5005/motta)) e usar o resultado disso para fazer os cálculos que deseja:

```
SELECT x.month,
       x.total AS 'total (100%)',
       (x.preventiva * 100) / x.total AS 'preventivas(%)',
       (x.corretivas * 100) / x.total AS 'corretivas(%)'
  FROM (
    SELECT MONTH(workOrderDate) AS month,
           COUNT(CASE WHEN workOrderDescription = 'preventiva' AND WorkType = '02' THEN 1 END) AS preventivas,
           COUNT(CASE WHEN workOrderDescription = 'CORRETIVA' THEN 1 END) AS corretivas,
           COUNT(CASE WHEN (workOrderDescription = 'preventiva' AND WorkType = '02') OR workOrderDescription = 'CORRETIVA' THEN 1 END) AS total
      FROM WorkOrder
     WHERE YEAR(workOrderDate) = 2018
       AND lastUpdateData IS NOT NULL
     GROUP BY MONTH(workOrderDate)
     ORDER BY MONTH(workOrderDate)
  ) x
```

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou!